# Generating CSR in keychain, private key not created osx

Tags: macos, push-notification, keychain, csr

I am generating a CSR to enable push notifications in my app (following the instructions here) http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

But when I create the CSR, it is supposed to create a private key in my keychain, but it hasn't.

The steps I have followed are:
1. open keychain access 
2. click "request certificate from a Certificate Authority..."
3. choose the save to disk option with common name "brendantest"
4. Look in keychain access for my private key, but it is not there.

Does anyone know why the key wouldn't show up or how to find it?
(on mac osx 10.7.4)

Answer (score 7):

I was bamboozled by this one too.

Turns out you need to highlight the 'login' section under keychains on the left first. Then it will create the private key when you do the CSR request.

Comment: 10 years later and this is still helpful

Comment: OMG, 1.this worked! 2.why Appleleeelele, whyaaaai ?

Answer (score 0):

I had to be connected to the internet, and signed into my apple developer account (and even then, it only works sometimes for me), but it will work when there is a checkbox under "saved to disk" that talks about custom key pairs or something.

I have managed to get my keys in there, but the next time I went to generate a new CSR, the option isn't there and the CSR doesn't put the keys in.